# How to compile XAML into C#?

Tags: c#, xaml

is there a way how to see XAML compiled into C#? It would be really useful because I would not have to look for "how to do something in WPF programatically".

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use **XAMLT** tool for this. It's XAML To C# converter. It is very useful if you newbie in XAML. It help you understand how to get the same things which you do in XAML in C#

This is a link to the soft:
http://www.xamlt.com/

Comment: Enter Sample.xaml. And just change xaml for what you need. In the below window C# code automatically changed and you see how to do the same in c#

Answer (score 0):

Found the perfect solution: XAML Code Behind Generator, see http://xamlgenerator.codeplex.com/.

Its a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 that allows you to compile XAML into the equivalent C#.